# How to get all holders from RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to get all holders from an recycler view in android.
The problem is that with my code i can only get only the holders from the visible elements(recyclerView.getChildAt(i)).

How can i get the elements that are recycled?

EDIT

Since i see that the question wasn't very clear, here is what i'm trying to do.

So i have a quiz, and i used a recyclerView for the questions. For every question, i have another recyclerView, in which i have the possible answers like a single selection. 
So, at the end of the test, i need to get the answers from every question not just the ones visible.

I did something and i stored every questionHolder in a list but now i think that the usage of recyclerView is wrong here and doesn't provide any advantage.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your question. Currently, it is very hard to help you with the content of your question. Please provide a minimal reproductible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If I am not wrong...then by [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView#glossary-of-terms) it means your view(particularly visible row item) are cached and reused again. I am not able to understand point of elements that are recycled?

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of the ViewHolders is that they are *recycled*. I.e. when an item scrolls offscreen the same holder may be used for an item that is appearing on the other end.

Items that are recycled are, well, recycled. So you can't get to them.
This seems like an [xy-problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You may have to rethink what you are trying to do.